# JSlider Modifies JLabel Size

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jlabel, jslider

I'm trying to make a Java program that has a JLabel that is directly modified by a JSlider. I've gotten all of the prettyness over with, but I can't get the Font to work on the JLabel. Below is my code.

```
int PIX_INIT = 24;
int PIX_MIN = 0;
int PIX_MAX = 100;
JCheckBox text;
JCheckBox slide;
JTextField size;
JSlider pixel;
JLabel label1;
JLabel label2;

//Adds header
    JPanel header = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    header.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    header.setSize(400, 50);
    header.setVisible(true);

        //Adds content to header
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        label1 = new JLabel("Marker Size: ");
        content.add(label1);

        size = new JTextField(5);
        content.add(size);

        label2 = new JLabel(" pixels");
        content.add(label2);
        header.add(content, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.add(header, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Adds body
    JPanel body = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    body.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    body.setSize(400, 325);
    body.setVisible(true);
    this.add(body, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//End body
//Creates slider

    //Adds slider
    pixel = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, PIX_MIN, PIX_MAX, PIX_INIT);
    pixel.setMajorTickSpacing( 10 );
    pixel.setPaintTicks(true);
    this.add(pixel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
//End slider

private class SliderHandler implements ChangeListener {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        pixel = (JSlider)e.getSource();
        int scale = pixel.getValue();
        Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, scale);
        label1.setFont(font);
        System.out.println(scale);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you add the ChangeListener to the slider?

```
pixel.addChangeListener( new SliderHandler() );
```

Comment: Yes I did. Forgot to post it, though.

Comment: @CoryMeeks, `Forgot to post it`  - in the future post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), otherwise we are wasting time guessing.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that I was using the correct code all along. Not quite sure how it happened, or why, but my code was trying to run code from another instance of this program. When I deleted the other instance it worked perfectly. If you have an answer as to why this happened, lay it on me. Much confused.